# how to get backward relation for a set of objects in django?

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a model for City and Province:

```
class Province(Model):
    name = CharField(...)


class City(Model):
    name = CharField(...)
    province = ForeignKey(Province,......, related_name='cities')
```

suppose I have populated the database as below:

```
ontario = Province.objects.create(name='Ontario')
quebec = Province.objects.create(name='Quebec')
alberta = Province.objects.create(name='alberta')
toronto = City.objects.create(province=ontario, name='Toronto')
waterloo = City.objects.create(province=ontario, name='Waterloo')
montreal = City.objects.create(province=quebec, name='Montreal')
calgary = City.objects.create(province=alberta, name='Calgary')
```

I can retrieve a queryset for all of the cities of ontario as below:

```
ontario.cities.all()
```

There are two objects in the above queryset: toronto and waterloo
How can I have a queryset of all cities of ontario and quebec?
suppose I have a queryset having ontario and quebec such as:

```
my_province_query = Province.objects.exclude(name__contains="Alberta")
```

I want to use this queryset to get Toronto, Waterloo, and Montreal

I first tried my_province_query.objects.all() but it is not possible to do this because query is not a model to get its objects. Any suggestion? 
Please note that I need all objects in a single queryset. I thought of running two different queries and then merging them together but I am seeking for a better method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need only the names of cities, the query could look like:

```
city_names = Province.objects.exclude(name__contains="Alberta").values_list('cities__name', flat=True)
# city_names == <QuerySet ['Toronto', 'Waterloo', 'Montreal']>
```

If you need actual `City` instances you could select `City` pks and then select the instances with another query:

```
city_pks = Province.objects.exclude(name__contains="Alberta").values_list('cities__pk', flat=True)
cities = City.objects.filter(pk__in=city_pks)
# cities == <QuerySet [<City: Toronto>, <City: Waterloo>, <City: Montreal>]
```

And if you want to get `City` instances hitting the database only once, you have to write your query using `City` [Manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/managers/#managers):

```
from django.db.models import Q

cities = City.objects.filter(~Q(province__name__in=['Alberta']))
# cities == <QuerySet [<City: Toronto>, <City: Waterloo>, <City: Montreal>]>
```

Comment: Thank you. The second case is my answer. However, I am new to django and do not understand what is this 'value_list' and 'flat=True'

Comment: @AminBa `values_list` selects a value or several values from a instances, instead of returning instances themselves. By default each value returned by `values_list` is wrapped in tuple, `flat=True` removes the tuples. Just play a little bit with theses options and you will see the difference.

Comment: I asked another question. I would appreciate if you could help me with that one too: stackoverflow.com/q/57133510/11065874 –